# jQuery Ajax File Upload error serialize

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, file-upload

Estou implementando um sistema de upload no meu sistema mais nao estou conseguindo recuperar os dados do upload via **serialze do jquery** quando passo os dados sem sem o input file ele funciona normal e nao me apresenta error.

PHP

```
<?php


namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\newsModel;
use Core\Base\Controller;

class adminNewsController extends Controller
{
    public $newsModel;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
       
        $this->newsModel = new newsModel();
    }


    public function index()
    {

        $this->renderView("admin/news/index", "layout");
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $this->renderView("admin/news/create", "layout");
    }


    public function ajax()
    {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') :
            $Action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'acao', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            switch ($Action):

                case 'form_cad':
                    $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);
                    dump($post);
                    break;

            endswitch;
        endif;
    }

}
```

JQuery/Ajax:

```
  $(selector).on("submit", 'form[name="form_cad"]', function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/adm/news/ajax',
                data: new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
            return false;

        });
```

HTML

```
<form action="" name="form_cad" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="">Titulo</label>
            <input name="news_title" class="form-control" type="text" value="sasasasa">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="">Imagem</label>
            <input type="file" name="news_images">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <textarea id="editor" name="news_content" class="'text-ckedt">sasaassaas</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<button name="cadastrar" type="submit"  class="btn btn-3d">CADASTRAR</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode usar `filter_input_array()` para `$_FILES` como você pode ver no [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input-array.php):

> `mixed filter_input_array ( int $type [, mixed $definition ] )`
>
> type
>
> One of INPUT_GET, INPUT_POST, INPUT_COOKIE, INPUT_SERVER, or
> INPUT_ENV.

Uma dentre algumas soluções seria usar o [filter_var_array($_FILES, $filters);](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php)